# Can I get email receiver name from linux mail server logs?

Tags: php, linux, email

I had a PHP script which called mail() function with FROM set as "Name Surname" with empty email ('Name Surname <>').
So I received the email with FROM set to 'Root User '. It was altered because email was empty.
Can I somehow retrieve the original 'Name Surname' from server (mail sender) logs?

Comment: server mail logs are only available as root, the sender can be parsed from the mail logs as can the recipient via a simple sed on command line or you can inspect the raw emails in the spool depending on your mail server setup.  None of this is php though so you're better asking this in superuser or serverfault

Comment: @Dave Thanks. I will contact root :)